# How do I get the expandable image from StatusBarNotification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am trying to get all the information from a StatusBarNotification (sbn). I've already set up the `NotificationListenerService`. I was able to get `EXTRA_TITLE`, `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_LARGE_ICON`. But I unable to get the expandable image.

I am checking the notification extras to see if any keys exist related to images. But all of them are returning `false` except `EXTRA_LARGE_ICON` if it's exists. `NotificationCompat.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON` returns the profile picture.

```kotlin
Log.d("EXTRA_BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URI",
    extras.containsKey(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URI))
Log.d("EXTRA_LARGE_ICON",
    extras.containsKey(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON))
Log.d("EXTRA_LARGE_ICON_BIG",
    extras.containsKey(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON_BIG))
Log.d("EXTRA_LARGE_ICON_BIG",
    extras.containsKey(NotificationCompat.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON))
Log.d("EXTRA_PICTURE",
    extras.containsKey(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE))
```

[image: Expandable notification image]

I am doing all these in `override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?)` method.

```kotlin
override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
    val extras = sbn.notification.extras
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your screenshot only showed notifications with a large icon?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to show the whatsapp expandable notification, just updated the image

Comment: `NotificationCompat.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON` returns the profile picture